# MySQL - allow connection from remote machine as root user

Tags: linux, mysql, root

When I installed MySQL server in Windows, there was an option "Allow root connection from remote machine". I checked that option and I had no probs when using it. I installed MySQL server in Ubuntu 9.04 using apt-get install. I can connect to the sql server from the same machine but when I try to connect from a virtual machine, it doesn't work. My guess is that I should allow root connection from remote machine. How to do that?

Comment: I think you mean MySQL?

Comment: yep. MySql. sorry, my bad. Updated now. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's done a little differently in mysql.  Take a look at the explanation here, it's not bad:

http://www.ntchosting.com/mysql/grant.html

the long, detailed version can be found here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

Another viable option if you don't wish to learn the full syntax is to install phpmyadmin - it can be a handy tool to have around, and it does somewhat simplify mysql privledges.  It's in the apt repository on ubuntu - be warned though that it is a web based application, and does require a web server to be installed to use it.